# attached source and Open Resource feature

Tags: eclipse

I have imported jars for a project under Libraries and attached the corresponding source zip. However, source files in the zip are not showing up in the Open Resource view (Ctrl + Shift + R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view the source by opening up the corresponding class. Eclipse will automatically show the appropriate source file instead.

Use Ctrl + Shift + T (Open Type) to open the class file.